# Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler and PrimeFaces dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I'm using FullAjaxExeptionHandler from omnifaces library and it all works well, however I'm not sure how to show the exception in PrimeFaces dialog on the page where exception happened.
Currently I can only redirect user to exception page as described on omnifaces showcase.

What I have now:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpages/bug.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

What I want:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/currentpage.xhtml?showExceptionDialog(exception)</location>
</error-page>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` doesn't support it. The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` is designed to achieve exactly the same behavior as if it were a non-ajax request. I.e. make use of `web.xml` specified `<error-page>` entries as per standard Servlet API.

Also, OmniFaces is not intented as an extension to specifically PrimeFaces, so it isn't possible to use any PrimeFaces specific APIs like `RequestContext` or the 4.0 "dialog framework" in `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`. It would make it unusable in projects where PrimeFaces isn't being used but a different component library.

Your best bet is indeed to create your own exception handler. You're completely free to take over parts of the source code of `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` as long as you respect the Apache license. An alternative would be to request [PrimeFaces Extensions](http://primefaces-extensions.github.io/) to create and add the exception handler you had in mind to its standard set.

Comment: Yes, I've created my own exception handler based on your code. I think my problem is that the handle() method of the exception handler is being executed in REQUEST_RESPONSE phase and that's too late to call any javascript. How can I tell JSF from this exception handler that I want to execute some javascript and make it render it?

Comment: Do the same as `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`: reset the response if it's not committed yet.

Comment: I've already tried that, but maybe I was doing something wrong as I'm quite new to JSF lifecycle. I'll give it another shot. Thanks.